# How to close the popup window in Telerik MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, popupwindow

I am using telerik MVC control and I am having a popup window and I want to close the pop up window by firing click event from my cancel button on the popup window .

Can someone tell me how should I do it ?

This is what I did

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="onClose()" />
```

and my java script is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function onClose() {  
        window.close();
    }  
</script>
```

but when I do that I get a confirmation box asking me whether I want to close the window and If I select yes my browser window is closed.

Comment: What did you do? there is no information here

Comment: @csharpsi: Oh, but there is. Someone just had to look at the source for the post, and make sure all the tags show up ;)

Comment: @Thomas Lycken - Ah I see. Now I understand ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a handle of the object

```
function GetRadWindow() {
                var oWindow = null;
                if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
                else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
                return oWindow;
            }
```

Then you can call close on the rad window object

```
function windowClose(reload) {
                var oWindow = GetRadWindow();                
                oWindow.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did a similar thing with the *asp.net-ajax window* from telerik.
They have demos out that helped me.

Try http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/window/clientsideapi for the mvc controls

Comment: you need to find the correct window to close. Like they did in the demo with jquery
var window = $("#Window").data("tWindow");